# Intrinsic current of the diode, what is its current?

Tags: current, diodes

I'm having some difficulty finding the diode's intrinsic current, I applied some formulas, but I don't know if it's correct. Could anyone tell me if this is correct or why it is wrong?

If this is right, I would like to understand why in the electric field we have to measure it in meters, but when I applied it in centimeters it went wrong, since the structure is in centimeters. Do you have to apply in meters anyway?  E = v/d

[image]

**answer below:**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's a diode?

Comment: @JohnD yes, What there was?

Comment: It seems to be doped with only boron, and no other dopant. So, ti doesn't seem to be a PN diode.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I agree with you, so much so that I insert the calculations according to the data I have but also insert the material type n with the same value as type P. I still don't know if the calculations are still correct, I put what I had in the statement

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is after the current that flows through an intrinsic semiconductor with an applied electric field.

We measure electric field EITHER in V/m or V/cm. (Or V/nm if you are perverse). If you start with a true equation and carry the units along with the numbers you must get the correct result WITH the correct units. This will be easiest if you use consistent units (all m for distance, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a diode. Just doped semiconductor (silicon.)

I'll be using the problem value for \$q\$. Yours is more precise. But I want to keep it simpler, for now.

#### getting an answer

The value of \$n_i=1\times 10^{10}\:\frac{\text{e}^-}{\text{cc}}\$ is typical for pure intrinsic silicon at \$T=300\:\text{K}\$. (GaAs has \$E_g\approx 1.4\:\text{eV}\$ and so would be much, much fewer conduction band electrons, for example.) So I conclude this is a silicon cube.

Without getting into the whys and wherefores about the *mass-action law*, you know that \$n\:p=n_i^2\$, given that pretty much all donors/acceptors are all ionized at \$T=300\:\text{K}\$, given that boron is an acceptor, and given that \$\left(p=1\times 10^{15}\right)\gg \left(n_i=1\times 10^{10}\right)\$, you can find that \$n=\frac{n_i^2}{p}=1\times 10^5\$.

Since \$\left(p=1\times 10^{15}\right)\gg \left(n=1\times 10^{5}\right)\$, ignore \$n\$ and just focus on \$p\$. So just use \$\mu_p\$ and ignore \$\mu_n\$: \$\sigma=q\,p\,\mu_p= 0.08 \:\frac{\mho}{\text{cm}}\$. That, times the applied volts, times the cross-section area, divided by the length gives you the current: \$800\:\mu\text{A}\$.

*(The part associated with \$q\,n\,\mu_n\$ is so small as to be ignorable -- about \$160\:\text{fA}\$.)*

#### looking over your work

When you tried to compute \$\sigma\$ you were, instead, computing the current density, \$J=\sigma\,\mathscr{E}\$.

You are supposed to use \$p\$ and not \$n_i\$. Another mistake.

You also screwed up on the units. It is true that \$\mu_p=500\:\frac{\text{cm}^2}{\text{V}\,\cdot\,\text{s}}\$. But note the use of \$\text{cm}\$. Meanwhile, you applied \$\mathscr{E}=1\times 10^6\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{m}}\$. But that's using \$\text{m}\$ and not \$\text{cm}\$. So you mixed up your units, even for computing \$J\$.

So even if you knew you were computing \$J\$ (which you don't appear to have known), you still got it wrong.

\$J=800\:\frac{\text{A}}{\text{cm}^2}\$.

Using \$J\$ instead, just to take a different tack, then \$I=A\,J=\left(10\:\mu\text{m}\right)^2\cdot 800\:\frac{\text{A}}{\text{cm}^2}=800\:\mu\text{A}\$.

#### summary

I think the answer should be \$I=800\:\mu\text{A}\$. *(Give or take a little.)*

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still have some questions. There are still some points that left me with doubts.

First regarding the calculation, I converted micrometers to centimeters because of the formula σ= 1/p = ((I*L)/(V*A)), to find it I needed to convert. Before the formula σ=q*(p*μp+µn*n)*E.
I ignored n, because I didn't have the information in the statement, but you demonstrated to me, I should have calculated and discovered the value of n=1*10^(5).

Comment: With the data in hand, I recalculated and the result matched, but I did not use the value of the electric field (E) in the calculation.
σ=1.602*10^(−19)*(1*10^(5)*1000+1*10^(15)*500) ▸ 80.1E−3

80.1E−3= ((I*1.E−3)/(10*1.E−6))

i=((0.0801*10*1.E−6)/(0.001)) ▸ i=801.E−6 A

I know that I must calculate the electric field, ([σ=q*(p*μp+µn*n)*E ]), but if I insert the electric field data it won't match the value 800 μA, I don't know what is happening, I see that it was just a coincidence calculation. Still, I need to know why.

Comment: Second: I hadn't realized that the electric field density could be used in the formula. I=J*A

But I realized that you calculated using the micrometer multiplied by centimeter, to work correctly I must convert the micrometer value to centimeters, thus achieving 800 microamperes, which is why I previously converted everything into centimeters.

Comment: @LUFER I just tossed \$n\$ away. It's way too small to care about. You can include it if you want. But I've nothing more to add about that bit. \$\mathscr{E}\$ is a million volts per meter, just as you computed. So I don't disagree with that. (It's also 10,000 volts per cm.) And it computes correctly when doing \$I=A\cdot\sigma\cdot\mathscr{E}\$. I've no problem reaching the right result so I'm not sure what the problem is. `0.08 siemens/cm * 1e6 volt/m * (10 micron)^2 = 800 uA`. It just works.

Comment: Sorry, when you demonstrated the calculation you simplified it, I like to make it clear where you use the values for J (sorry). Regarding the calculation using the electric field according to the formula σ=q*(µp*p+n*μn)*E.
σ= 1/p = ((I*L)/(V*A))
See the 3 resolutions:
1° Not complicating the electric field (I know that n is negligible, but I still want to use it).
σ=1.602*10^(−19)*(1*10^(5)*1000+1*10^(15)*500) ▸ 80.1E−3 (without electric field)
i=((0.0801*10*1.E−6)/(0.001)) ▸ i=801.E−6 A (Here you get your answer)

Comment: 2° Using electric field converted into centimeters.
E=((V)/(d))→ (cm) E=((10)/(0.001)) ▸ 10.E3 (according to the theory the electric field d the scale has to be in meters, but the calculations are in scale in centimeters)
σ=1.602*10^(−19)*(1*10^(5)*1000+1*10^(15)*500)*10000. ▸ 801.E0
i=((8.01*10*1.E−6)/(0.001)) ▸ i=80.1E−3
2° Using electric field converted into meters. (of course the current will go up)
Result: i=8.01 A

My doubt is why I can't find the same value that you got using this formula.

Comment: @LUFER If you don't use my name in your comments, then I don't see them. It's been days. Just came back. See them now. Sorry about the delay.... What's the official answer for this problem? Do you think I got it wrong? Or are you just trying to figure out how to get the answer I gave? I may try to expand things if I understand why I should bother. So let me know.